# Solution to a set of points in the plane

Tags: java, points, plane

With a coworker we are looking for a method to calculate the maximum number of points in a plane 2D that can communicate as long distance they can represented by "D", the code is requested on Java and each one of the points must be considered as an object with two coordinates, "X" and "Y" who must be represented as 2 int in the code.

We found that if we select any of this points in the plane, is possible determinate the radius D of the circle around the point selected, where all of the mid points contained inside of this radius can communicate with the target point. 
Then after that you can use alliterations for determinate all the communications in each plane 2D at a determinate distance "D" and find which is the zone with maximum number of communications between all the mid points.

After all the mentioned my question is the following:

Exist another way more easy to do it in Java?

Some friend suggest to us do it in C# language because it includes a library which facilitates this kind of representation with the use of pointers and the memory addresses, but is a primordial requirement to do it in Java.

If you have any suggestions or a better way to approach our problem would be very appreciated for us.

Comment: So, in essence what you're trying to do is search for all of the points within a certain plane and identify the boundary on the plane?
It sounds like you're looking for an algorithm for a convex set search, but your question isn't super clear. If that's what you're looking for, there are many ways to approach this problem.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because SO requires code debugging questions to be [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit your question according the guidelines.

Comment: @Roderick Lenz That's exactly what I'm looking for and excuse me if I wasn't very clear on the question, I need ideas or a possible solution for this specific case for implement in Java.

Comment: @jrook Excuse me if I did not comply with the rules when I published my question, I will review it again and edit my question, also thanks for the advice.

Comment: @jrook Great idea, and a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment auto expands to [mcve]. Less typing for same/more detail.

Comment: "_Some friend suggest to us do it in C# language because it includes a library which facilitates this kind of representation with the use of pointers and the memory addresses, but is a primordial requirement to do it in Java_"  Why is this information relevant ?

Comment: @c0der Because maybe there is a similar solution in java, anyway I appreciate all the answers.

Comment: [How to ask:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague"  I believe it means focused and as short as possible questions.

Comment: @c0der: Thanks for the suggestion I asked another question how you mention me and I received better answers.